# jQuery datatable immediately hide column

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I got the jQuery datatable hide column feature to work properly.  The following code will hide the 2nd column of the table:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="btn toggle-vis" data-column="1" id="hideColumn">Show/Hide</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var table = $('#example1').DataTable();

  $('a.toggle-vis').on('click', function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
    column.visible( ! column.visible());
  });
}
```

What I would like to do is initially hide the column when the user first enters the page.  The column will only show when clicked.

How do I go about adjusting the code to achieve this effect?

Comment: `var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));`

Comment: @clearshot66 - Thanks.  Updated.

Comment: Where's your HTML so we can see what you want to hide? You should see this: https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html

Comment: @clearshot66 - I'm using PHP to generate the table (this was old code).  I was trying to prevent having to show the code for the table.  But there is are header tags, with which the 2nd one is the column I want to hide.  Please note that the above < a > tag successfully hides the necessary column.  I just need to hide the column as soon as the user enters the page.

Comment: As what I sent..

Comment: @clearshot66 - The link you provided is exactly what I used to get the hide function to work.  I did not see anything on that page that tells you how to initially hide a column on document.ready, which is why I'm here on StackOverflow now.  Unless I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use columnDefs

Try:

```
var table = $('#example1').DataTable(
{
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 2 ],
            "visible": false
        }
    ]
} );
```

EDIT

I'm not sure why that doesn't work.  Adding the code in here since in the comment did not display well. 
Try this instead:

```
var table = $('#example1').DataTable(); 
table.column(1).visible(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  There were no errors, while at the same time, no success.

Comment: That is actually a zero based index of the column, so that should be [1] for the second column.

Comment: Not sure why that doesn't work, but you could try 

`var table = $('#example1').DataTable();
table.column(1).visible(false);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function () {    
    // To hide the table header during page load
    $("#example1 tr th:nth-child(2)").hide();

    // To hide the 2nd column during page load    
    $("#example1 tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });


    // Hide and show while clicking the link
    $(".toggle-vis").click(function () {
        var col = $(this).data("column");

        // Hide/Show the header
        $("#example1 tr th:nth-child(" + col + ")").is(":visible") ? $("#example1 tr th:nth-child(" + col + ")").hide() : $("#example1 tr th:nth-child(" + col + ")").show();

        // Hide/Show the details
        $("#example1 tr td:nth-child(" + col + ")").each(function () {
            $(this).is(":visible") ? $(this).hide() : $(this).show();
        });
    });

});
```